# Type 'String' has no member 'cacheIntermediates' error when I try to set the option for CIContext

Tags: ios, swift, caching

I'm using `Xcode 10` building for `iOS 11`. I can't seem to get the `cacheIntermediates:false` option to work, even though the docs say it's available when building for `iOS 10` or greater.

```
lazy var ciContext: CIContext = { [unowned self] in
    return CIContext(mtlDevice: self.device!, 
                     options:[.cacheIntermediates:false]) 
}()
```

This code above give me the following error:

> Type 'String' has no member 'cacheIntermediates'

Comment: You need to be using swift 4.2 for the enum

Comment: Check the SWIFT_VERSION of your target's Build Settings.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** As other users have mentioned, this was caused by my Swift compile version set to 4 instead of 4.2!

**Old:**

Even though they showed it working with ".cacheIntermediates" on WWDC 2018, you need to use the enum value:

```
return CIContext(mtlDevice: self.device!, options:[kCIContextCacheIntermediates:false])
```